# How to return value that is in a relation of specific index. If value came from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that input fag is informasjonsvitenskap in list(FagKode), if that is true i want it to print the values in karak that has the code INFO, like INFO100,INFO132 and INFO233. And if input fag is økonomi i want it to print the values in karak the has the code ECON. i also have a function, def legg_til(). thats will allow me to add an element in the list 'emner'. then the question will be. How to make it find the value that is in relation to input fag and print the specific value. :/

```
print('\nVelkommen til karakterprogrammet Infinitux\n')
print('----------------------------')

print('1: Emneliste','2: Legg til emne','3: Sett karakter','4: Karaktersnitt','5: Avslutt',sep='\n')
print('----------------------------')

emner = ['INFO100','INFO132','INFO233']
FagKode = [['informasjonsvitenskap','INFO'],['økonomi','ECON']]
karak = [['INFO100','C'],['INFO132','B'],['INFO233','C'],['ECON218','A']]


def start():
    global meny
    global fag
    meny = int(input('Tast inn ønsket valg (press 0 for meny): '))

    if meny == 1:
      valg_fag = input('Press Enter for å velge fag/emner (Skriv "alle" for å vise alle fag/emner)\n: ')

    if meny == 1 and valg_fag == 'alle':
      for i in karak:
        print(*i)

    elif meny == 1 and valg_fag == '':
      fag = input('- Fag: ')
      emnenivå = int(input('- Nivå: '))
      try:
        if fag in FagKode[0] and emnenivå in range(1,1000):
          ???????
          ???????
        else:
          print('Du har gjort noe feil!')
      except ValueError:
          print('NEI')


def legg_til():
    global meny
    global fag
    if meny == 2:
      add = input('Nytt emne:  ')
      emner.append(add.upper())


def karakter(): # Sletter/Setter ny karakter
    global meny
    if meny == 3:
      valg_emne = input('Emne: ')
      slett = input('Karakter (<enter> for å slette): '+karak==valg_emne)


    if meny == 3 and valg_emne in emner and slett == '':
      for i in range(len(karak)):
        if karak[i][0] == valg_emne:
          del karak[i][1]
        start()

    if meny == 3 and valg_emne in emner:
      pass

    if meny == 3 and valg_emne in emner and slett == 'HEI':
      for i in range(len(karak)):
        if karak[i][0] == valg_emne:
          print(karak[i][1])

def snitt():
  pass


def programslutt():
  global meny
  if meny == 5:
    print('Takk for nå, velkommen igjen!')
  else:
    ('Feil verdi')


start()
legg_til()
karakter()
programslutt()
```

Thanks for opinions in advance :)

Comment: Why do you have the values in Lists. Why don't you use the dictionary to hold key value pairs. For the variables **FagKode** and **karak**

Comment: i have not gone throug dictionaries yet, i will do that after this assignment. i know that it would be better if i used dictionaries.

Comment: The list  i want to return values from was written wrong, the list i want the return values from is karak, not emner

Comment: There are much more efficient ways of checking if a number falls within a range... you should explain what is the exact problem you're trying to solve

Comment: What is `karak==` for? in the switch case below line:
 `if fag in FagKode[0] and emnenivå in range(1,1000):`

Comment: Let's say that input fag is informasjonsvitenskap in list(FagKode), if that is true i want it to print the values in karak that has the code INFO, like INFO100,INFO132 and INFO233. And if input fag is økonomi i want it to print the values in karak the has the code ECON. i also have a function, def legg_til(). thats will allow me to add an element in the list 'emner'. then the question will be. How to make it find the value that is in relation to input fag and return me the specific value. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Make the variables **FagKode** and **karak** as dictionaries.

and try to get the values as follows.

```
return karak.get(FagKode.get(input(fag)))
```

or this for list.

```
for i, j in FagKode:
    if i==input(fag):
        for k, l in karak:
            if k==j:
                return l
return "Not Found"
```

Comment: Sukumar Rdjf, i would prefer dictionaries but i have to use list this time because this is an assignment in school. :/

Comment: Now does it only give me the value i give to input.

Comment: Why don't you just post the ldata and logic where you are trying to check the elements. There is too data which is irrelevant to the logic in the question.

Comment: What do you mean ? i dident understand that

Comment: Sukumar Rdjf.                                                                                        
Let's say that input fag is informasjonsvitenskap in list(FagKode), if that is true i want it to print the values in karak that has the code INFO, like INFO100,INFO132 and INFO233. And if input fag is økonomi i want it to print the values in karak the has the code ECON. i also have a function, def legg_til(). thats will allow me to add an element in the list 'emner'. then the question will be. How to make it find the value that is in relation to input fag and return me the specific value. :/